# jQuery selector to query XML

Tags: jquery, xml, jquery-selectors

I know that my selector values and my xml variables aren't connected, but I can't quite figure out how to connect them. I know that the xml is coming through, but I need to link it to the content displayed once the value is selected. Here's what I have:

New Code

```
<script src="js/xmlDom.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var cityID;
var city;
var amt;


$(document).ready(function() {


$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "data/precipData.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: makeItRain
    });

    });

function makeItRain(xml) {
    console.log($.xmlDOM(xml));
    $.xmlDOM(xml).find("Row").each(function () {
        cityID = $(this).attr("id");
        city = $(this).find("city").text();
        amt = $(this).find("amt").text();
        $('<option>' + city + '</option>').appendTo('.selectCity');
        console.log('appending');

        $(".selectCity").change(function () {

            $('select option:selected', this).append(cityID);
            $(".name").append(city);
            console.log('city');
            $(".ammount").append(amt);
            console.log('amt');

        });
        //.change();


    });
};

</script>
</head>

<body>

<select class="selectCity">
                <option id="default">Select a city</option>

</select>
<div class="name">

</div>
<div class="ammount">

</div>
</body>
```

Old Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var cityID;
var city;
var amt;


$(document).ready(function() {


$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "data/precipData.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: makeItRain
    });
});


function makeItRain(xml) {

$(xml).find("Row").each(function(){

    cityID = $(this).attr("id");
    city = $(this).find("city").text();
            amt = $(this).find("amt").text();

    $('<option>' + city + '</option>').appendTo('.selectCity');
    console.log('appending');

    $(".selectCity").change(function() {

        $('select option:selected', this).append(cityID);
            $(".name").append(city);
            console.log('city');
            $(".ammount").append(amt);
            console.log('amt');

      });
      //.change();


    });
};
</script>
</head>

<body>

<select class="selectCity">
                <option id="default">Select a city</option>

</select>
<div class="name">

</div>
<div class="ammount">

</div>
```

Comment: jquery queries html, xml wasn't ever invited to the party.

Comment: Right, so can you help me?

Comment: I changed the code to this based on your answer, but I can't seem to get the xml to load with AJAX at all. The page only logs xmlDOM...

I'm going to add an edit...

Comment: if the xml data isn't being sent back to the ajax call then isn't that a server side issue then?

Comment: do a console.log(xml) to confirm that the data is actually not loading.

Comment: I know that it isn't loading because I am running it on a local server and it isn't logging anything.

Comment: can you add a console.log at the very first line of `makeItRain`

Comment: It's logging everything until this line.
    $.xmlDOM(xml).find("Row").each(function ()

Answer (score 3):

Your logic is right, the ajax call (and callback) are put well in place. The only problem is that our buddy jQuery is only friends with HTML (and us too), and never wanted to be friends with XML because xQuery never took care of HTML when HTML had nobody and wept alone (John Resig is the true superman)

#### OMGOMG no XML querying!

Fortunately this isn't a big problem, amazing libraries and plugins have been written by humanitarians all around the world to solve this issue, one which I can name to you would be:

**[xmlDOM](http://outwestmedia.com/jquery-plugins/xmldom/)** this is a jQuery plugin which makes the elusive XML querying a dream come true.

#### Good news

If we use **[xmlDOM](http://outwestmedia.com/jquery-plugins/xmldom/)** your code will not have to be changed too much, the following is your new code:

```
function makeItRain(xml) {
        console.log($.xmlDOM(xml));
        $.xmlDOM(xml).find("Row").each(function () {
            cityID = $(this).attr("id");
            city = $(this).find("city").text();
            amt = $(this).find("amt").text();
            $('<option>' + city + '</option>').appendTo('.selectCity');
            console.log('appending');

            $(".selectCity").change(function () {

                $('select option:selected', this).append(cityID);
                $(".name").append(city);
                console.log('city');
                $(".ammount").append(amt);
                console.log('amt');

            });
            //.change();
        });
    };
```

#### Demonstration

http://jsfiddle.net/aTxYc/1/